# Pre-signing Amazon S3 urls for both HEAD and GET verbs

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm hosting files on Amazon S3 that I want to make accessible using [pre-signed urls](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth).

For simple GET requests this works perfectly. There are some clients however that perform a HEAD request first (to retrieve the file size). Since the signature in the URL includes the http verb (GET vs HEAD), the head request fails.

The client simply does:

```
HEAD http://(bucketname).s3.amazonaws.com/filename?AWSAccessKeyId=(mykey)&Expires=(timestamp)&Signature=(sig)
GET http://(bucketname).s3.amazonaws.com/filename?AWSAccessKeyId=(mykey)&Expires=(timestamp)&Signature=(sig)
```

I cannot change the clients to use a different url for head and get. Is there a way to make amazon use a signature that accepts both HEAD and GET for the same resource?

Comment: I'm running in to the same problem, and really need a fix for this. Did you ever find a way to fix this?

Answer (score 25):

You can also simulate the `HEAD` behavior with `GET` if you specify `Range` header for first byte only. The difference will be that you receive `206` instead of `200` code. Secondly full size will be in `Content-Range` header.

`curl -r 0-0 <URL>`

Comment: I think that should be `curl -H "Range: bytes=0-0" <URL>`, i.e. without the `-I`, as that still does a `HEAD` request and results in a 403 (for me, at least).

Comment: Curl has the `-r` flag to specify the range, so you can just do: `curl -r 0-0 <URL>`.

Answer (score 7):

No. The `HEAD` and the `GET` need different signatures as there are subtle differences in the signature inputs.

Not sure what you're using to generate the pre-signed authentication URLs, but I know that some of the official AWS SDKs handle this, while others don't *yet*.

Comment: are you saying you know some of the SDK's support multiple verbs? which ones? or am i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 7):

with the help of a friend, I found a solution that works for me: proxy the HEAD request on my server, and redirect for the GET request.

When a request comes in with a HEAD verb to get the file info, I use my S3 code on my server to get the HEAD info and then I sent it back to the requestor myself.

When a request comes in with a GET verb to get the file itself, I do a 302 redirect with a pre-signed URL.

this works perfectly to handle both HEAD and GET by not needing to pre-sign both. I only pre-sign the GET request for the actual file.

Comment: this is a valid workaround but it makes my server a bottleneck between client and s3, which I was trying to avoid by using presigned URLs

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only presign the url for either `GET` or `HEAD` and not both,
We solved this by using `xmlhttprequest`.

We use it to start the get request, grab the status/headers and abort the request.

```js
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

async function getUrlStatus(url, timeout=1000){
    const start = Date.now();
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let status_code;
    // Start async get call
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    // Detect status change. Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 2) {
            console.log("Headers Received", xhr.status);
            console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())
        } else if (xhr.readyState == 3) {
            // Update the status code
            status_code = xhr.status;
            xhr.abort();
            console.log("Loading", status_code);
            return status_code
        }

    }
    function resolveReadyState(resolve, reject){
        if (status_code == 200)
            resolve(status_code);
        else if (status_code == 403)
            resolve(status_code);
        else if (timeout && (Date.now() - start) >= timeout)
            reject(new Error("Timeout"));
        else
            setTimeout(resolveReadyState.bind(this, resolve, reject));
    }
    xhr.send()
    return new Promise(resolveReadyState)
}

url = "https://some_presigned_file_url"

getUrlStatus(url).then(status_code => console.log("Received State". status_code))
```