# Gradle failing to download dependency when HEAD request fails

Tags: http, gradle, amazon-s3

I have set up a dependency in my Gradle build script, which is hosted on Bitbucket.

Gradle fails to download it, with error message

> Could not HEAD 'https://bitbucket.org/....zip'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I looked into it, and it seems that this is because :

- Bitbucket redirects to an amazon url
- the Amazon url doesn't accept HEAD requests, only GET requests

I could check that by testing that URL with curl, and I also got a 403 Forbidden when sending a HEAD request with curl.

Otherwise, it could be because Amazon doesn't accept the signature in the HEAD request, which should be different from the GET one, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717230/pre-signing-amazon-s3-urls-for-both-head-and-get-verbs?rq=1).

Is there a way around this ? Could I tell Gradle to skip the HEAD request, and go straight to the GET request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem by using the [`gradle-download-task`](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task) plugin, and manually writing caching as explained [here](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/issues/89)